# Keyboard didn't appear, FBConnect on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, qwerty

I follow this guide to integrate facebook on my app iPhone: [here](https://github.com/shazron/fbconnect-iphone)
But When I click FConnect and I try to insert my user and psw didn't appear the keyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

pls check your code if you have this line than it means you close it.

```
textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

[keyboard type maybe you need to define yourself?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006896-CH3-SW12)

and you can use the original example from facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios)

Comment: I Check the code for userInteractionEnabled but it don't found.